# Can I have a jMeter user "click" on a resulting link?

Tags: jmeter

I'm looking into the possibilities of jmeter, and it looks just great. However, one of the things my testing script should be able to do, is search for some values, and click on a random resulting link.
So what I would need to automate is:

- Entering the values in the searchbox (I could do this by using the correct GET url in a second page, but how do I do this 5000 times?)
- Clicking on one of the results listed.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using the CSV Data Set, it loads a CSV file, and feeds the content into the variables of your choice:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config

After that, you can use the regular expression extractor to extract the URL's you want from the resulting HTML, and follow those links:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor

Answer (score 0):

You could use a HTML Link Parser for your second part (the clicking on one of the results):

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTML_Link_Parser

See http://theworkaholic.blogspot.co.at/2009/11/randomly-clicking-links-in-jmeter.html for an example of using the link parser in a context similar to your question.